# Generate random numbers from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, ab-testing

I'd like to make a client-side A/B testing library.

Each user has a random number stored in a cookie. Each test has a test name and an array of options. I need a function that picks a random option given the user's random number, the test name, and the options. Of course, the function must always return the same option for a given set of inputs.

How can I write this function in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My current solution uses the [CryptoJS library's MD5](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) hashing function to generate a random number:

```
// seed is the user's random number

choose_option = function(seed, test_name, options) {
  word = CryptoJS.MD5("" + seed + test_name).words[0]; // take first 32-bit word
  i = Math.abs(word % options.length);
  return options[i];
}
```

Comment: This sounds perfect given your requirements - do you have any particular objection to this technique, or are you just curious if there's anything else out there?

Comment: @Bubbles I'm hoping that there is something simpler, which doesn't require a dependency on an external library. I'm also worried that I've introduced some statistical bias or dependence between tests.

Comment: It's also possible to generate the numbers in a specific range. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034013/generate-a-number-in-a-specific-range-from-a-checksum

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit later and a bit exagerate as the lib in question has many feature you may not use, but I always have this included in my projects so let me expose my solution to the very same problem you had. This lib can be initalized with a seed ([chancejs#seed](http://chancejs.com/#seed)), very useful for creating repeatable results:

```
const Chance = require('chance');
c1 = Chance('email@gmail.com', 'maybe a uuid here');
c1.integer();
c1.natural({min:1000,max:9999});

c2 = Chance('foo-baz-bar');
c2.string();
c2.word();
...
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var availNum= [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12];
//@var count number of random num you want 
function createRandomData(count) {
    var data = [],
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var random = availNum[Math.floor(Math.random() * availNum.length)],

        data.push({
          random:random 
        });
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using strings for numbers?

Comment: sorry i have changed @Brad