# Generate a number in a specific range from a checksum

Tags: javascript, md5, checksum

I'm working on a number generator that takes a string as input, and produces a number in a specific range as output. In order to do this, I'll need to determine the minimum and maximum possible value that an md5 checksum can have, and then convert the md5 checksum to a number in that range. How can I convert an md5 checksum to a number in a specified range?

```
function getNumberInRange(md5checksum, min, max){
    //generate a number between min to max, inclusive, using the md5 checksum that is entered in the input.
    //Every input should have exactly one output.
}
```

Comment: In order to do this, I'd need to know the minimum and maximum possible value of an md5 checksum (in base 10, instead of in hexadecimal). Then I'd need to convert the md5 checksum to a base-10 number, and use that number to obtain a number in the specified range.

Comment: What do random numbers have to do with it?  "Every input should have exactly one output"... not very random.

Comment: @Brad Perhaps I should use the word "checksum" instead.

Comment: So you want to take a 256-bit integer and truncate it to be within a certain range?

Comment: @Brad Yes, that's basically what I'm trying to do. Of course, the output should be within the range that is specified in the function's parameters.

Comment: What I think you want to do is take `max - min`, get the number of bits required to represent this integer, truncate your 256-bit value (generated with MD5 in your case) to the number of bits, add the `min` value to this, and output.  Then, add a ceiling if the number is too large?  Not sure really where to go from here.  You basically want a hash function with fewer bits in the output, I think.

Comment: @Brad (checksum/checksumMax)*(max-min)+min might work also. In this case, checksumMax would be the maximum value that the checksum could have, represented in base 10. I haven't tested it yet, though.